# Update record with previous row

Tags: sql-server, insert-update

I have a situation where I need to update the records with previous row value.

Source:

```
|MatId | BaseId |Flag|Pkg1| CS1
--------------------------------
|3001  | 3001   | 1  | 20 | 2 |
|3002  | 3001   | 0  | 15 | 3 |
|3003  | 3001   | 0  | 10 | 4 |
```

Here both 3001 (`MatID`) and 3001(`BaseID`) are same so `FLAG`  =1, in the next record only `BASEID` is same. The output should be **only `PKG1`** field updated with the current row value.

Target or output:

```
|MatId | BaseId|Flag|Pkg1|CS1
------------------------------
|3001  | 3001  | 1  | 20 | 2|
|3002  | 3001  | 0  | 20 | 3|
|3003  | 3001  | 0  | 20 | 4|
```

As seen in the target above i have to update the two values in PKG1 with the value from first record 20. Also there are many columns with Pkg1, how to update all the columns with a single query?

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You did not specify an `ORDER` to what you expect to be the previous row.  Assuming from your example it is ordered ASCENDING from the MatID.

Comment: It is ordered ascending from BaseId

Comment: Do you want to update `Pkg1` if `BaseID` = previous `MatID`, right?

Comment: @Megatron yes that's correct

Comment: Ok, and is `MatId` unique?

Comment: Yes MatId is unique. I forgot to mention, there will be many fields that are starting with Pkg like Pkg1, Pkg2 etc. So i have to update all those fields that are starting with Pkg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get Previous and Next value with the help of [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125(v=sql.120).aspx) and [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.120).aspx) Function in SQL Server is very simple. If you are using an earlier version of SQL Server than 2012 which does not support `LEAD` and `LAG` function we can use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Try to use something like this:

```
;WITH t AS
(
    select LAG(MatId) OVER (ORDER BY MatId) AS previousMatId
    ,      BaseId
    ,      MatId
    from   TABLE
)
update tab
set    tab.Pkg1 = p.Pkg1
from   TABLE tab
       inner join t on tab.MatId = t.MatId and t.BaseId = t.previousMatId
       left join (select MatId AS MatId 
                  ,     ISNULL(LAG(Pkg1) OVER (ORDER BY MatId), Pkg1) AS Pkg1
                  from TABLE) p on t.MatId = p.MatId
```

Comment: Thank you i will try and update. One question in the query pkg1 is set as 999999, i want it to be the previous record value. Or i am missing something here.

Comment: So, you want to update `Pkg1` to previous `Pkg1` when `BaseID` = previous `MatID`. Am I right?

Comment: yes correct. The current record in PKg1 will be updated with previous record in Pkg1 when previous baseid = previous matid and current baseid = previous matid

Comment: I ran your query and it works, but the current records become 99999. I want to get the previous record value 20 like in example. Also it updated only one record, There are 2 more records to be updated with value 20, What modification on query will help to update the other records.

Comment: Ok, I will modify the answer in a few minute. Please use the edit link on your question to add this additional information

Comment: @Arun.K Thanks and please try the new version

Comment: i ran the query. It says 3 rows affected but the records are not updated in the table. It shows the same value 15 and 10.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. see the screen http://prntscr.com/8wi8gp. Is it expected result on the screen?

Comment: Yes for the first two records. For the third and 4th record the combination of matid and base id are different. But pkg value is correct though.

Comment: I modified the query as per your screen shot but it still says 3 records affected but no change in the records. Showing the same value.

Comment: Ok i combined both of your queries and arrived at something. It seems working for test cases, will test and update you guys. Thanks a ton for the help. I think i have to write update statement for each columns with pkg in it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying the newer mats need to be updated with the Pkg1 belonging to the original mat?  If so it would be:

```
update NewMats
set NewMats.Pkg1 = Base.Pkg1
from MyTabe as NewMats
inner join (select BaseId, Pkg1
            from MyTable
            where BaseId = MatId) as Base
on Base.BaseId = NewMats.BaseId
where NewMats.BaseId < NewMats.MatId
```

But if this is the case, then your data model needs to be changed.  The rule is that a given piece of information should live in only one place. So maybe break this out into 2 tables that are related.

Comment: Thank you. Your query worked but only for one record not for the two records. I need to update for two records based on the first record.

Comment: Ok i combined both of your queries and arrived at something. It seems working for test cases, will test and update you guys. Thanks a ton for the help. I think i have to write update statement for each columns with pkg in it.

Comment: @Arun.K it looks to me like you should have a parent table that has pkg in it, and then related child tables that have things that vary per version in it (MatId, CS1, etc.)