# Stored proc to copy previous/next relationship between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I have a table where I store data about files; the files are linked using the PreviousFileId and NextFileID fields, here is an example of the data:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------------+
| FileID | FileCode | FileOrder | PreviousFileID | NextFileID | ParentFileCode |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|   1000 | FILE-A   |         1 | NULL           | 1001       | NULL           |
|   1001 | FILE-B   |         2 | 1000           | 1002       | NULL           |
|   1002 | FILE-C   |         3 | 1001           | NULL       | NULL           |
|   1003 | FILE-D   |         1 | NULL           | NULL       | FILE-A         |
|   1004 | FILE-E   |         2 | NULL           | NULL       | FILE-B         |
|   1005 | FILE-F   |         3 | NULL           | NULL       | FILE-C         |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------------+
```

I want to create a stored procedure to update the link between the files 1003, 1004 and 1005. The procedure should accept as parameter the ParentFileCode, so for example if I pass ‘FILE-B’ as parameter the data should look like this after the execution of the stored procedure:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------------+
| FileID | FileCode | FileOrder | PreviousFileID | NextFileID | ParentFileCode |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|   1000 | FILE-A   |         1 | NULL           | 1001       | NULL           |
|   1001 | FILE-B   |         2 | 1000           | 1002       | NULL           |
|   1002 | FILE-C   |         3 | 1001           | NULL       | NULL           |
|   1003 | FILE-D   |         1 | NULL           | 1004       | FILE-A         |
|   1004 | FILE-E   |         2 | 1003           | 1005       | FILE-B         |
|   1005 | FILE-F   |         3 | 1004           | NULL       | FILE-C         |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------------+
```

Here is the table structure/insert data code:

```
CREATE TABLE Files
(
FileID INT NOT NULL,
FileCode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FileOrder INT NOT NULL,
PreviousFileID INT NULL,
NextFileID INT NULL,
ParentFileCode VARCHAR(20) NULL
)



INSERT INTO dbo.Files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode)
VALUES (1000, 'FILE-A', 1, NULL, 1001, NULL)


INSERT INTO dbo.Files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode)
VALUES (1001, 'FILE-B', 2, 1000, 1002, NULL)


INSERT INTO dbo.Files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode)
VALUES (1002, 'FILE-C', 3, 1001, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO dbo.Files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode)
VALUES (1003, 'FILE-D', 1, NULL, NULL, 'FILE-A')


INSERT INTO dbo.Files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode)
VALUES (1004, 'FILE-E', 2, NULL, NULL, 'FILE-B')


INSERT INTO dbo.Files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode)
VALUES (1005, 'FILE-F', 3, NULL, NULL, 'FILE-C')
```

Any idea on how I can achieve that?

Comment: How does passing `File-B` cause the desired results you have here. Totally missing the logic here.

Comment: And couldn't you just do this with `lag()` and `lead()` in a single update statement?

Comment: I think it's updating next and previous file id. And I would also think lead() and lag(). Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402252/update-record-with-previous-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I made your sample data into a temporary table, as I found this easier to work with:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#files') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #files;

CREATE TABLE #files (
    FileID INT NOT NULL,
    FileCode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FileOrder INT NOT NULL,
    PreviousFileID INT NULL,
    NextFileID INT NULL,
    ParentFileCode VARCHAR(20) NULL);

INSERT INTO #files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode) VALUES (1000, 'FILE-A', 1, NULL, 1001, NULL);
INSERT INTO #files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode) VALUES (1001, 'FILE-B', 2, 1000, 1002, NULL);
INSERT INTO #files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode) VALUES (1002, 'FILE-C', 3, 1001, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO #files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode) VALUES (1003, 'FILE-D', 1, NULL, NULL, 'FILE-A');
INSERT INTO #files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode) VALUES (1004, 'FILE-E', 2, NULL, NULL, 'FILE-B');
INSERT INTO #files (FileID, FileCode, FileOrder, PreviousFileID, NextFileID, ParentFileCode) VALUES (1005, 'FILE-F', 3, NULL, NULL, 'FILE-C');
```

Method 1 is to do what Daniel said, with a few tweaks (to make 0s into NULLs, and because you can't use `LEAD`/ `LAG` directly in an `UPDATE`):

```
--Method #1
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        FileId,
        PreviousFileID = LAG(FileId, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY FileOrder),
        NextFileID = LEAD(FileId, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY FileOrder)
    FROM
        #files f
    WHERE
        ParentFileCode IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE
    f
SET
    PreviousFileId = x.PreviousFileId,
    NextFileId = x.NextFileId
FROM
    #files f
    INNER JOIN x ON x.FileId = f.FileId;
```

Note that this doesn't take a parameter, it just updates the entire table.

Here's a method using three UPDATE statements, that does sort of take a parameter:

```
--Method #2
DECLARE @file VARCHAR(50) = 'FILE-B';

UPDATE
    fx
SET
    PreviousFileId = fxp.FileID,
    NextFileID = fxn.FileId
FROM
    #files f --Anchor
    LEFT JOIN #files p ON p.FileID = f.PreviousFileID --previous file
    LEFT JOIN #files n ON n.FileId = f.NextFileID --current file
    INNER JOIN #files fx ON fx.ParentFileCode = 'FILE-B' --files to update
    LEFT JOIN #files fxp ON fxp.ParentFileCode = p.FileCode
    LEFT JOIN #files fxn ON fxn.ParentFileCode = n.FileCode
WHERE
    f.FileCode = @file;

UPDATE
    fxp
SET
    NextFileID = fx.FileId
FROM
    #files f --Anchor
    LEFT JOIN #files p ON p.FileID = f.PreviousFileID --previous file
    LEFT JOIN #files n ON n.FileId = f.NextFileID --current file
    INNER JOIN #files fx ON fx.ParentFileCode = 'FILE-B' --files to update
    INNER JOIN #files fxp ON fxp.ParentFileCode = p.FileCode
WHERE
    f.FileCode = @file

UPDATE
    fxn
SET
    PreviousFileId = fx.FileID
FROM
    #files f --Anchor
    LEFT JOIN #files p ON p.FileID = f.PreviousFileID --previous file
    LEFT JOIN #files n ON n.FileId = f.NextFileID --current file
    INNER JOIN #files fx ON fx.ParentFileCode = 'FILE-B' --files to update
    INNER JOIN #files fxn ON fxn.ParentFileCode = n.FileCode
WHERE
    f.FileCode = @file;
```

Both methods work on this small set of data, so I would suggest testing these against larger data sets?  You would then need to make them into a stored procedure, which is simply going to be a case of adding `CREATE PROCEDURE`... etc.

Comment: I have an old version of SQL Server, so, no LAG or LEAD, the second method is working fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
update table
set 
previousfileid= lag(fileid, 1, 0)  over(order by fileorder) ,
nextfileid= lead(fileid, 1, 0)  over(order by fileorder) 
from table_name
where parentfilecode is not null
```

Comment: Old version of SQL sever, I can't use LEAD or LAG