# Insert corresponding row field in first row and so on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named ABC. I want to insert corresponding row EditedDate into NextDate of first row and so on.

For example second row edited date i.e 2017-07-18 09:47:56.000 should be inserted to NextDate of first row and third row EditedDate i.e 2017-08-06 12:38:51.000 should be inserted to second row NextDate and so on.
the last row Next Date should be Today Date.

[image]

Comment: For SQL Server you can use the LAG operator. This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402252/update-record-with-previous-row

If that does not help, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
SELECT *,
   LEAD(EditedDate,1, GETDATE()) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId 
                                      ORDER BY EditedDate) AS NextDate
                     --SYSDATE if Oracle
FROM ABC;
```

Comment: I also need to insert NextDate Into NextDate Field