# SQL Server: how to update a column with a value that is in that column when another number in another column is >1

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a table with the following data:

```
Part    Comp   level  item_nbr
-------------------------------
abc     ab      1      1
null    cd      2      2
null    ef      3      3
cde     gh      1      4
null    ij      2      5
null    kl      3      6
null    mn      4      7
```

I would like to update the nulls to the value  in each level 1, so every level that is >1 is updated with the level one value.

```
Part    Comp   level   
---------------------
abc     ab      1     
abc     cd      2  
abc     ef      3  
cde     gh      1    
cde     ij      2  
cde     kl      3  
cde     mn      4
```

I am at a loss as to how to achieve this on a very large dataset. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To explain another way,
    part  level
    abc     1
            2
            3
Then the next row is populated with another part
    efg     1
            2
            2

## etc.

**Further clarification:**

I need the string"abc" to be filled down with the string "abc" while the column fields below are null.  The next row has a string of efg and the following column fields below are null, again, those fields should be filled down with the value "efg" and so on.

The level field = 1 will always have a part number, but all the other levels report up to the level 1 part, so should be populated identically.  And repeat.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: How do you know which part a given row with `null` in the part column relates to? i.e. what data in the row allows you to know that rows 2 & 3 in your example are related to row 1?

Comment: You can use window functions to achieve this, but the database needs to know how the rows should be ordered to be able to do this. To expand on @DaleBurrell's point: the database is not constrained to keeping the table in the order the rows were inserted in. Which ORDER BY statement can be used to ensure the rows are shown in the correct order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update record with previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402252/update-record-with-previous-row)

Comment: @DaleBurrell the nulls should = the part above it with a level 1.

Comment: @pbeentje, there are actual 2 that can be used.  level can be used, it will have 1-15 levels, each level 1 has a part number.  The levels are incremental because there can be many parts at any given level, but I have only exploded the bom out to 15 levels.  The second column that can be used is an incremental row number of the whole table.  My thought was that the level column should be used because it starts back at 1 for each different part, for example  part abc has 3 level, next part cde again starts at 1 and ends at 4.

Comment: @vanlash do how do you ensure the correct order of the records? Are you saying there is also an id field, and that all ids refer to the last part number before? If so please update your data to show this.

Comment: I meant the Level field is not incremental (1,2,2,3,3,4,5) etc.  But the item_nbr column gives the exact order.

Comment: @DaleBurrell The Level field can be used as an order field.  Because the part field number will always be identical for all lines between 1 and 15.  When the level field restarts at 1, then there is a corresponding part number in the part field, that will then need to be filled down until the level field reaches 15.

Comment: But you seem to be assuming that SQL Server will return you the results in the order you enter them - which is not the case (as @pbeentje said above). So you need another column to ensure they are ordered correctly e.g. an identity, or timestamp column.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I do have a identity column that I didn't list.  it is item_nbr.  This can be used as an order by

Comment: @DaleBurrell  Please see updated illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an updatable CTE with window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(part) over (partition by itm_nbr_not_null) as new_part
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when part is not null then item_nbr end) over (order by item_nbr) as itm_nbr_not_null
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set part = new_part
    where part is null;
```

You can run the CTE to see what is happening.

Comment: I can't thank you all for enough for your help. What a great community! This was much simplier than I was trying to make it.  I never thought of doing a partition by the item_nbr not null.  Works perfect!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

well, from your question what I understand is, you need to update the null column's value until you get a not null value. and you want to continue it up to the last row of the table.
for that scenario, I created a stored procedure, where I read the value of every n-th cell if it is null I changing it with the prev. cell's value, when the cell was not null.

Approach:

1. create a temporary table/ table variable.
2. add an extra column, which is basically identity, which will help to rank the column.
3. iterate a loop until the maximum row is reached.
4. in each iteration, read the cell value for the i-th row

   4.1 if it is not null put it in a temporary variable.

   4.2 else, replace/update the i-th cell's value with the temporary variable
5. continue it, until you reached up to the last row of the table/table variable.

look at my following snippets:

```
create proc DemoPost
as
begin
declare @table table(serial_no int identity(1,1), name varchar(30), text varchar(30), level int)
insert @table
select Name, Text, Level from Demo
declare @max as int = (select max(serial_no) from @table)
--select @max
declare @i as int =0
declare @temp as varchar(30)
declare @text as varchar(30)

while @i < @max
begin   
    set @i = @i +1
    set @temp = (select name from @table where serial_no = @i)
    -- if @temp is not null, fetch its value, otherwise, update/replace it with 
    -- previously gotten not-null cell's value.
    if @temp is not null
    begin
        set @text = (select name from @table where serial_no = @i)
    end
    else
    begin
        update @table
        set name = @text where serial_no = @i 
    end
end

select name, text, level from @table
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update it using temporary table according to the given scenario i thought item_nbr is unique in row Hope this will help

```
SELECT  *
INTO    #TEMP
FROM    URTablehere

DECLARE @PRev VARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    URTablehere
      ) > 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ID INT 
        DECLARE @Part VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @Num INT 


        SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                @ID = level ,
                @Part = Part ,
                @Num = item_nbr
        FROM    #TEMP
        IF ( @ID = 1 )
            BEGIN 
                SELECT  @PRev = @Part
            END 

        IF ( @ID > 1
             AND @Part IS NULL
           )
            BEGIN

                UPDATE  URTablehere
                SET     Part = @PRev
                WHERE   item_nbr = @Num

            END 

        DELETE 
        FROM    #TEMP WHERE item_nbr=@Num




    END
```