# Update every row with data from row above

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to update every row of my table with values from row above depends on some values.

Let's say that my table looks like this:

```
  |storeID|   Date   | Stock  | Medition | Regularized |
    --------------------------------
    |   1   |2019-01-01|  500   |   550    |      1      |
    |   1   |2019-01-02|  500   |    0     |      0      |
    |   1   |2019-01-03|  500   |    0     |      0      |
    |   2   |2019-01-01|  250   |   300    |      1      |
    |   2   |2019-01-02|  250   |   350    |      0      |
    |   2   |2019-01-03|  250   |    0     |      0      |
```

And output has to look like this:

```
|storeID|   Date   | Stock  | Medition | Regularized |
--------------------------------
|   1   |2019-01-01|  500   |   550    |      1      |
|   1   |2019-01-02|  550   |    0     |      0      |
|   1   |2019-01-03|  550   |    0     |      0      |
|   2   |2019-01-01|  250   |   300    |      1      |
|   2   |2019-01-02|  300   |   350    |      0      |
|   2   |2019-01-03|  300   |    0     |      0      |
```

When a store has been regularized, its stock must be the amount of the medition in next day.
Sometimes a medition has been made but stock hasn't to be regularized.
I tried some things with recursive tables and read a few post with similar issues ([Update record with previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402252/update-record-with-previous-row)) but still i'm not able to solve my problem.

**Imagine that i have a tank full of fuel. Every day I have sales and inputs and the stock of the tank goes changing.
Any day i can do a medition to check if the real stock (medition) matches with the stock i wrote in the "books" (stock)
If it's different and i check as 1 last column (Regularized), the stock next day will be the medition i did the day before.
IF i check as 0 last column, the stock will be the same than day before even if i did a medition.

Thanks for every help you could provide me.

Comment: Why does the final row have a value of `300` for `stock` and not `350`?

Comment: Any time you've tried something and it didn't work, post what you tried, and what was wrong with the result.   Why were you not able to solve this with the LAG or LEAD function?   Why shouldn't this question be closed as a duplicate of the question you linked to?

Comment: Last row has stock 300 because regularized column has 0 last day, so the stock hasn't to be changed.

Comment: So the change is recursive, as it needs to use the first row's value (for that storeID)?

Comment: @larnu seems mistakenly written 1 in first place

Comment: The logic is inconsistant here. If the last row should be `300`, then  the 2nd row should have a value of 500, as the value of `Regularized` is `0`. *Something* is wrong here, as the same logic does not apply to both sets.

Comment: Why does the Regularized column changes from sample data to the expected results? (5th row)

Comment: I think i failed to explain what i 'm trying to achieve. I've edited my post to try clarified it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use CROSS APPLY to join the table to itself.

```
UPDATE st SET
    stock = u.Medition
FROM SomeTable st
CROSS APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 Medition 
            FROM SomeTable i
            WHERE i.storeID = st.storeID
            AND i.[Date] <= st.[Date]
            AND i.Regularized = 1
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC) u
WHERE st.Regularized = 0;
```

Comment: I haven't tested, I'll admit, but I'm not sure this'll work. Based on the OP's last comment, as the last row would have a value of `350` for `Stock`, but it should be `300`. Looks like this needs recursion. :/ *(tested, and as I thought, last row is wrong [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3bfa08b0077c03a41cc7f2c70d31843))*

Comment: @Larnu I failed to see that the Regularized column changed. I'm suspecting some problem between the sample data and expected results. However, I'm going to delete this answer as it  does not really solve the problem. I'll wait for further clarification.

Comment: Yeah, something is wrong. Either rows 2 & 3 are incorrect, or that last row is.

Comment: Apparently my solution was correct but the sample data was incorrect.

Comment: I've tried this and the problem is that I get the first medition in the stock for all the rows to the same store.
I think i failed to explain what i 'm trying to achieve.
I've edited my post to try clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one regularized row for each storeid

```
UPDATE INPUT_TABLE IT  
SET STOCK = ( SELECT MEDICATION FROM INPUT_TABLE ITI WHERE IT.STOREID = ITI.STOREID AND ITI.Regularized =1 )
WHERE IT.Regularized =0
```

Hope this helps